# Badge Count is not shown in iOS App

Tags: ios

The Badge count is not shown in my app for background and termination cases.
I added this code in appdelegate didfinishlaunch

```
 UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0

        if #available(iOS 10, *)
        {
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]) { (granted, error) in

                guard error == nil else
                {
                    return
                }
                if granted
                {
                    UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            let settings : UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .sound , .badge], categories: nil)
            UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
            UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        }



 UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber += 1
 print("Badge Count ===>   \( UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber)")
```

The print shows correct count. But not shown in the app.

Actually I dont need to update badge count for each notification. For some share or like we need to update badge count. So I created a method and update the count.

```
func setBadgeCount()
        {
            if(self.currentAppState() == 1 || self.currentAppState() == 3)
            {
                sleep(2)
                UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber += 1
                print("Badge Count ===>   \( UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber)")
     }
        }
```

callthis method from

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)
    {

setBadgeCount()
}
```

Comment: try to comment this line UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
and check again

Comment: Can you please share your payload information.

Answer (score 0):

The app is not going to update the badge number with this method unless the app is actually open. If you want to update the badge number upon receiving a notification then you have to set the badge number in the payload of notification. Below is the sample of payload looks like. Put your desired number there and send it will work.

```
{
    "aps": {
        "alert": "Test Push Notification",
        "sound": "yourSound.aiff",
        "Badge": "desiredNumber"
    }
}
```

Comment: The notification is given by the cloud server itself with badge count 0

Comment: That's the problem. Badge count shouldn't be 0. If it is zero it won't be shown

Comment: The cloud gives zero. For each notification, I updated it by 
UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber += 1
When I print the count, it shows the correct count. When adding brkpoints, the count shhown in app.

Comment: In this way, the count only will be shown when it is in foreground. It won't work when app is terminated. When app is terminated.

Comment: If you want to increase when app is in background you have to update the badge number in didReciveRemoteNotification method

Answer (score 0):

You have written this code in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` which is called only once. So how would it update badge number.
Only add `UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0` in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

Instead use,

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveLocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification) {

    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = application.applicationIconBadgeNumber + 1; 
}
```

For push notification use,

```
func application(application: UIApplication,didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {

    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = application.applicationIconBadgeNumber + 1; 
}
```

As per your updated question, you are not getting proper badge count when app is entering background or terminating , while you are getting proper log. This is because to handle these cases we need to store badge counts somewhere. You can store it in `UserDefaults` and then fetch it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to onesignal message settings and turn on badge count[image]